# Replace VLookup Values with VLookup Images (Google Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, rounding, vlookup, percentage

Afternoon everyone! Before reading, I'd review the example sheet.

I'm struggling with a line of code, where it will allow me to replace the value in a cell that is found using VLookup with a picture.

*Link to example sheet:*
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hL0KbRSf2MHFwDOgjERP_iayXgfOIR0lMtz0p7YfFs4/edit?usp=sharing

**The dilemma**

I'm using `Vlookup` to find a value on "Sheet3" and to place the percent value in a particular cell on "Sheet1" (No issues there). Once the correct value is found, I want to `Vlookup` the correct image to that cell that corresponds with the percent value.

Things to keep in mind.

- I cannot alter "Sheet3" in any way.
- I can only alter "Sheet1" and "Images"

Here is the formula I'm currently using to find the correct value:

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP($E7, Sheet3!$B$16:AC, 10, False), " ")
```

Here is the formula I'm using to try and find the image:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($E6, Sheet3!$B$16:AC, 10, False)=ISBETWEEN(VLOOKUP($E6, Sheet3!$B$16:AC, 10, False),24%,26%), VLOOKUP($H6, Images!$A1, 1, False)," ")
```

**What I want**

If the "SKU" value ($E6) is found on "Sheet3", find the percent value on column $K (on "Sheet3") linked to that "SKU", and show the correct image on "Sheet1" on cell ($H6) if the percent value is between 24%-26%. If the statement is false then the cell will just show up blank (" ").

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Images sheet to:

[image]

then use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(ROUND(
 VLOOKUP($E6, Sheet3!$B$16:AC, 10, 0), 2)), Images!A:B, 2, 1))
```

[image]